# Calling controller method (ASP MVC3) method from ajax doesn't work

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using the following syntax to make a call to controller method from ASP page.

```
$.ajax({
             url: 'ControllerName/MethodName',
             type: 'POST',
             contentType: 'application/json;',
             data: JSON.stringify({ param: param1}),
             success: function () {
                 alert("Success!!!");
             },
             error: function () {
                 alert("Failed!!!");
             }
         });
```

I have two ASP pages (views), both having same controller. If I call above method from first page, controller method gets called successfully. But if call same method from second page I get alert message "Failed". Also I tried using GET type, tried with other controller methods and all. Nothing will be called from second view. can anyone help me what can be problem? I am new to MVC.

Comment: What is the HTTP code coming back in the failed request?

Comment: put this  error: function(jqXHR, exception) on the error function and print jqXHR

Comment: i think your controller is not sending the json data. If it is returning as `return View();` change it as `return Json(true);`

Comment: Actually I don't have anything to return back. Just I want to do some other operation inside the method. Still I tried sending back some data, but same error comes.

Comment: try returning `return Json(true);` if you want nothing to return. Also change `url: 'ControllerName/MethodName',` to `url: '/ControllerName/MethodName',`

Comment: @jose : I added error: function(jqXHR, exception) , exception shows "error" thats it. jqXHR has status:12030, StatusMessage: ""

Comment: @Karthik: Hey thanks a lot. It worked when I chaned `ControllerName/MethodName`, to `/ControllerName/MethodName`. But I did not return anything from controller method, still works.

Answer (score 0):

Since your ajax is expecting result of JSON data from your Controller method do you have return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)?

Answer (score 0):

Try change content type to:

```
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
```

or/and specify url using mvc helper like:

```
url: @Url.Action("action"),
```

Works in my example. Hope it will help.